# How can I add a clickable font awesome icon within a div tag?

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I would like to make an icon within a div tag clickable. See code below:

```
<div class="wd_home_box">
<div class="fa fa-get-pocket"><a href="leadership">&nbsp;</a></div>
<a href="leadership">Leadership</a></div>
```

Ideally, I would like the whole box to be clickable, but I'll settle for just the icon and text obviously. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Change the 2nd line to: <a href="leadership"><i class="fa fa-get-pocket"></i></a> https://jsfiddle.net/beyynu7e/

Comment: That worked perfectly, Thank you!!

Comment: I spoke too soon. The CMS I'm using stripped the i tags out so when I went to re-edit the code it disappeared.

Comment: @JakeBraun why make two anchors in the same div? instead why not just wrap the div with one anchor? That way you don't have an un-clickable area between the two anchors.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I agree 100%. When I responded my only reservation in consolidating the code more was that we were not provided the context of this snippet with the matching CSS. I didn't know all the ramifications of merging the anchor tags, and thus provided the most minimal modification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/0j1me71m/1/

```
<div class="wd_home_box">
    <a href="leadership"><div><i class="fa fa-get-pocket"></i>&nbsp;Leadership</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works at first but the CMS I use removes the i class tags so once I go back in to re-edit an item everything is broke. I need to be able to make the entire box clickable without using i class at all.

Comment: I'm using a platform my company built in house. It functions similarly to Wordpress @adam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92208/discussion-between-big-show-and-adam-buchanan-smith).